# Override attributes in static XSD to further define custom requirements

Tags: xsd

We are using the IBM Common Base Event specification XSD to monitor application health. However, we have custom attributes defined in the extendedDataElementsname tag.

I would like to distribute an application or situation specific XSD that includes the IBM XSD but with these extended data elements further defined and restricted. For example, here is a snippet of our XML:

```
<situationInformation extensionName="Feed" creationTime="2008-02-08T12:00:00">  
    <extendedDataElements name="Feed" type="string">    
        <children name="interfaceType" type="string">
               <values>ABC</values>
        </children>
        <children name="fileName" type="string">    
            <values>file.txt </values>
        </children>
        <children name="processedTime" type="dateTime">
            <values>2008-02-087T12:10:00</values>
        </children> 
    </extendedDataElements>
<situationType category="REPORT" successDisposition="SUCCESSFUL" situationQualifier="File" reasoningScope="INFO"/>  
</situationInformation>
```

So, from the above I would like to create an XSD (that imports or includes the IBM XSD?) that defines the necessary application specific attributes (interfaceType, fileName, processedTime, etc) as well as overrides the IBM XSD restriction of maxLength=64 (make it more restrictive).

[IBM XSD Link](http://xml.coverpages.org/IBMCommonBaseEventV111-XSD.html)

Hope I explained that well...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try using [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). From my experience, it does a pretty good job at reverse engineering one or more XML files into a human readable and logical XML schema.

I also had a need of making an XSD schema from an existing XML file. Tried Altova XML Spy. It did produce a compilant schema, but it was a mess.

Trang did it much more successfully and I was really impressed what it produced, so I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have tried tools like trang. My problem is that I want to override the attributes from the main xsd in a supplemental one. For example, those tools pull from the ibm xsd and produce the say fileName attribute as the generic name="name" type="type". I want to override and specify name="fileName" type="string" (as well as override any maxlength or minlength restrictions)